# Accesing Spring context from Hazelcast executeOnKeyOwner

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I have a `MultiMap` in Hazelcast with a `List<SomeObject>` for each `String` key and want to persist each list with something like

```
IExecutorService executorService = hzInstance.getExecutorService("commonExec");
//...
executorService.executeOnKeyOwner(new PersistTask(key), key);
```

but the `PersistTask` object need another object defined in the Spring context. If I understand correctly, the instance of `PersistTask` is created, then serialized and sent to the key owner and the executed there. How do I reference the local Spring context? I think I could try to access it statically but I feel filthy for doing that. Is there a better way? For the record, I'm using Hazelcast 3.5.3 and Spring 4.2.3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better and more object-oriented solution: you can add the annotation `@SpringAware` to your class (in my case `PersistTask`) and it will be initialized using the Spring context after deserialization. All the Spring annotations and interfaces (`@Autowired` and `InitializingBean` for example) will be processed and the dependencies will be injected. For this to work, you must define a `ManagedContext` in the Hazelcast instance. The `SpringManagedContext` is what you need. This can be specified in the XML config like this:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hzexample">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:spring-aware />        <!-- this line here !!! -->
        <hz:instance-name>hzexample</hz:instance-name>
...
```

The example in the official blog is [this](http://blog.hazelcast.com/dont-call-us-hazelcast-will-call-you/) but it is formatted badly.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Hazelcast provide some kind of dependency injector. Your object (in my case, `PersistTask`) must implement `HazelcastInstanceAware` and it will be injected the local Hazelcast instance after deserialization. You can add objects in a user context that can be retrieved from the Hazelcast instance. [The Hazlcast blog](http://blog.hazelcast.com/user-context/) has a nice example.